# .htaccess rewrite to redirect only root access to a specific subdirectory, while other folders are kept

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

is there way I can do a .htaccess rewrite to redirect only root access to a specific subdirectory, while other folders are kept.

What I have got is

```
www.testing.com/a
www.testing.com/b
www.testing.com/c
```

And I would like to keep

```
www.testing.com/a
www.testing.com/b
```

and redirect any access to 
`www.testing.com` to `www.testing.com/c` transparently so user would see still see `www.testing.com` on URL bar

I've tried `RedirectMatch` but it just redirects everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ /c/ [L]
```

This will do **silent rewrite** from `www.testing.com/` to `www.testing.com/c/`